# Issue with split and data.table

Tags: r, split, data.table

I have a data.table that I want to split into a list and then modify.  I'm discovering some weird behavior when I try to delete a column on one of the data.tables in the list after calling split.  Here's a MWE (that throws an error and causes my R session to crash):

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(level = c(1, 1, 2, 2), value = 1:4)
list = split(d, f = d$level)
list[[1]][, level := NULL]
list
```

I get:

```
Error in .shallow(x, cols = cols, retain.key = TRUE) : Internal error: length(names)>0 but <length(dt)
```

Comment: I think it was fixed in the devel version (not sure though). Either way, [GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/new) is the correct place to report bugs in general.

Comment: you should give some more context on  what you're trying to do, as this looks like something better accomplished another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use `l` name for a variable instead of `list`.
This seems to be a bug caused by split.data.frame method utilized in the process.
I've quite recently proposed a new split.data.table method defined below. It seems to address your problem.

**Update 2016-03-30:**

`split.data.table` has been implemented in data.table 1.9.7. Now use can simply use:

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(level = c(1, 1, 2, 2), value = 1:4)
l = split(d, by = "level")
l[[1L]][, level := NULL]
l
#$`1`
#   value
#1:     1
#2:     2
#
#$`2`
#   level value
#1:     2     3
#2:     2     4
```

---

The old answer below, it may be useful if you stuck with 1.9.6 or below. Be aware that it won't handle factor levels the same way as `split.data.frame`, this isn't the case for method developed in data.table 1.9.7 which is consistent to data.frame method.

```
library(data.table)
split.data.table = function(x, f, drop = FALSE, by, flatten = FALSE, ...){
    if(missing(by) && !missing(f)) by = f
    stopifnot(!missing(by), is.character(by), is.logical(drop), is.logical(flatten), !".ll" %in% names(x), by %in% names(x))
    if(!flatten){
        .by = by[1L]
        tmp = x[, list(.ll=list(.SD)), by = .by, .SDcols = if(drop) setdiff(names(x), .by) else names(x)]
        setattr(ll <- tmp$.ll, "names", tmp[[.by]])
        if(length(by) > 1L) return(lapply(ll, split.data.table, drop = drop, by = by[-1L])) else return(ll)
    } else {
        tmp = x[, list(.ll=list(.SD)), by=by, .SDcols = if(drop) setdiff(names(x), by) else names(x)]
        setattr(ll <- tmp$.ll, 'names', tmp[, .(nm = paste(.SD, collapse = ".")), by = by, .SDcols = by]$nm)
        return(ll)
    }
}
d = data.table(level = c(1, 1, 2, 2), value = 1:4)
l = split.data.table(d, by = "level")
# below setattr to be addressed in split.data.table
invisible(lapply(l, setattr, ".data.table.locked", NULL))
l[[1]][, level := NULL]
l
#$`1`
#   value
#1:     1
#2:     2
#
#$`2`
#   level value
#1:     2     3
#2:     2     4
```

I've also filled a bug report describing your case, you can find it in [data.table#1481](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1481).